# How to show chinese html file in jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, encode

I used jQuery tabs widget in my page with ajax mode, something like

```
<li><a href="changelog/web.html" title="web">WEB</a></li>
```

changelog/web.html is already declared charset as gb2312 in its  tag and it can be shown normally in iframe. But in target div of jQuery tabs, all the chinese characters in web.html are unreadable code.
I've already set "contentType: "text/html; charset=gb2312" in ajaxOptions for jQuery tab, but it still not work.

so what can I do now? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem some days ago. The web.html has wrong encode. I re-create a copy of the file with utf-8 then it works well.